# How to add to stored procedure call selected vallue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys have select in stored procedure (myProc) like this :

```
SELECT @body = 'User: ' + @admin_username  + ' set Admin role TO: ' + [username] 
FROM [dbo].[users]
WHERE [id] = @user_id;
```

and want add  `@body` in another stored procedure call which is in current procedure

```
exec sendMail '','',@body
```

How do it ? `@body` type is `nvarchar(max)` I think i have wrong select because when i exec my procedure have an error : **cannot insert the null value**

Comment: I strongly suggest to pass parameters by names, like `exec sendMail @body = @body`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your @Admin_Username and [Username] doesn't return a null, otherwise your whole @body variable will end up with a NULL.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT @body = 'User: ' + ISNULL(@admin_username, '')  + ' set Admin role TO: ' + ISNULL([username], '')
FROM [dbo].[users]
WHERE [id] = @user_id;


exec sendMail '','',@body
```

Answer (score 0):

If the username column is null for a given user_id then @body will return NULL. Use ISNULL([username],'') to at least return an empty string for the username.

Also try using an OUTPUT parameter to return @body to the next stored procedure. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx